# The native JNI Library 'mqjbnd' was not found. For a client installation this is expected (3=mqjbnd)

Tags: java

I am using Websphere V8.5 in RAD. While trying to create queue connection Getting the following error. If i am testing the same code in standard java application getting the connection object. But in webapplication it is not working.

Here is my code

```
MQQueueconnectionFactory factory=new MQQueueconnectionFactory();
factory.setHostName(HostName);
factory.setTransportType(1);
factory.setPort(1414);
factory.setChannel(ChannelName);
factory.setQueueManager(Queuemanagername);
connection=factory.createQueueConnection();
connection.start();
```

Error

```
    "Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found. [3=mqjbnd]

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd in java.library.path
```

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa9if.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the code and log to the question please

Comment: I have attached my error Log

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Set 'client mode' if you write client, [more](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/websphere-mq-client-installation-missing-mqjbdll-files)

```
factory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```

[Configure libraries](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=jms-configuring-java-native-interface-jni-libraries) if you start in default `XMSC_WMQ_CM_BINDINGS` mode.